# Is it possible to reverse the Grouping in a GroupDataModel

Tags: listview, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I have a `GroupDataModel` of items and use this to populate a `ListView`. Each item has a category, which can be either "TV" or "Cinema". I set "category" as a sorting key and the `ListView` displays the items grouped into categories.

However, the order of categories is "Cinema" then "TV". I need them to be in the other order: "TV" then "Cinema".

Is this possible?

Code:

```
GroupDataModel* results = new GroupDataModel();
results->setGrouping(ItemGrouping::ByFullValue);
QStringList sortingKeys;
sortingKeys.append("category");
results->setSortingKeys(sortingKeys);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reverse the sorting using the method [`setSortedAscending(bool ascending)`](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__groupdatamodel.html#setsortedascending). If you set it to `false`, the items are sorted in descending order, if `true`, they are sorted in ascending order.

Comment: In not able to test this yet but will this change the order of the categories or just the items within the categories?

Comment: I can confirm this changes the order of the categories. Many thanks.